# NSIS Installer failed to start/stop service

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm using WindowsXP, NSIS 2.46 with `nsSCM` plug-in, and have 4 machines with nearly the same environment(hardware + software) since they come from a same GHOST image but with very limited changes on application layer(no any system settings changed).

I'm using NSIS installer to install my application to them, detail process are:

1. Stop 'Apache2.2' service.
2. Copy files to Apache root folder.
3. CreateShortCut
   With script:

> ```
>  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\Stop.lnk" "$SYSDIR\sc.exe" "stop MyAppService" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll" 27 SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
>  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\ShowDemo.lnk" "$PROGRAMFILES\MyAppPath\MyAppShowDemoHelper.exe" "-b 102" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll" 24 SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
> ```

4. Start 'Apache2.2' service.

   With script:

> ```
>   nsSCM::Start /NOUNLOAD "Apache2.2"
>   Pop $0 ; return error/success
>   ${If} $0 == "success"
>       MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "Successfully started 'Apache2.2' service"
>   ${Else}
>       MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP|MB_OK "Failed to start 'Apache2.2' service with result: $0, Contact help desk or start it manually!"
>   ${EndIf}
> ```

===========================

Now the problem is the **step 4**, **in two of those machines**, it always popup ERROR and always need manually to start the service(with no error), but meantime, the shortcuts are created successfully.

I've checked system logs, Apache logs, but no error logs/message could be found.

I spend one day and tried everything, at last, I found once I remove the Step 3, everything is fine, so any idea Why?

[Edit0]:

For work around, I have to switch Step 3 and 4, at least now it works good.

Comment: CreateShortcut should be totally unrelated to a plugin call, I'm pretty sure there is something else going on. Are you using NSIS 3 beta or NSIS 2.46?

Comment: @Anders I can't believe that either until I comment out script row by row, and saw the result.   I'm using NSIS 2.46.

Comment: @Anders Any suggestion to minimize the scope?

Comment: @Shawn: Could you try stopping/starting service with native windows tool; i.e. net command. `!insertmacro ShellExecWait "open" "net" "stop ${_SERVICENAME}" "" SW_HIDE ""`; In case you need ShellExecute macro let me know.

Comment: @Shawn I'll try to create some code that uses the system plugin and prints error codes as it does its thing but it might take a day or two. If that works then it might be a problem with the plugin. Have you tried any of the other service plugins/macros from the wiki? ( http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service )

Answer (score 0):

CreateShortcut should have no impact on plugins so this is rather strange. It would be nice if we could narrow this down to a problem with the plugin API in NSIS or a problem in the plugin itself. Maybe you could try the [SimpleSC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin) plugin?

Here is some code that does it manually with the system plugin. It is not pretty but should display a relevant error code if it fails.

```
Section
!define MyServiceName "Spooler" ;"stisvc" 
ExecWait '"$SysDir\cmd.exe" /c net stop "${MyServiceName}"' ; Hack to make sure the service is stopped so we can try starting it again
Sleep 1111

InitPluginsDir
CreateShortcut "$PluginsDir\Test1.lnk" "$ExePath" ; Create some dummy shortcuts to possibly trigger the bug
CreateShortcut "$PluginsDir\Test2.lnk" "$ExePath"

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Util.nsh
!define ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING 1056
!define SC_MANAGER_CONNECT 0x0001
!define SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS 0x0004
!define SERVICE_START 0x0010
!define SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE 0x0040
!define SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE 3
!define SERVICE_STOPPED 1
!define SERVICE_START_PENDING 2
!define SERVICE_STOP_PENDING 3
!define SERVICE_RUNNING 4
!define SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING 5
!define SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING 6
!define SERVICE_PAUSED 7

!macro WaitForServiceRunningStatus_
System::Store S
Pop $6
Pop $1
System::Call KERNEL32::GetTickCount()i.r7
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i,i,i,i)i.r2'
loop:
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::QueryServiceStatus(ir1, ir2)i.r3'
    System::Call '*$2(i,i.r4)'
    ${If} $3 <> 0
        ${If} $4 = ${SERVICE_RUNNING}
            DetailPrint 'Service is now running.'
        ${Else}
            Sleep 250
            System::Call KERNEL32::GetTickCount()i.r8
            ${IfThen} $8 < $7 ${|} StrCpy $7 $8 ${|} ; Reset on GetTickCount rollover
            IntOp $8 $8 - $7
            IntCmpU $8 $6 "" loop
            DetailPrint 'Timeout! Service status is $4'
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
System::Free $2
System::Store L
!macroend
!macro WaitForServiceRunningStatus hSC MsTimeout
Push ${hSC}
Push ${MsTimeout}
${CallArtificialFunction} WaitForServiceRunningStatus_
!macroend

System::Call 'ADVAPI32::OpenSCManager(t"", i0, i${SC_MANAGER_CONNECT})i.r0 ?e'
Pop $9
${If} $0 = 0
    DetailPrint 'OpenSCManager(t"", i0, i${SC_MANAGER_CONNECT}) failed with error $9'
${Else}
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::OpenService(ir0, t"${MyServiceName}", i${SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS}|${SERVICE_START}|${SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE})i.r1 ?e'
    Pop $9
    ${If} $1 = 0
        DetailPrint 'OpenService("${MyServiceName}") failed with error $9'
    ${Else}
        System::Call '*(i,i,i,i,i,i,i)i.r2'
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::QueryServiceStatus(ir1, ir2)i.r3 ?e'
        Pop $9
        ${If} $3 = 0
            DetailPrint 'QueryServiceStatus failed with error $9'
            StrCpy $4 0 ; We failed, set to unused code so we stop processing
        ${Else}
            System::Call '*$2(i.r3,i.r4,i.r5,i,i,i,i)'
            IntFmt $3 "%#x" $3
            IntFmt $4 "%#x" $4
            IntFmt $5 "%#x" $5
            DetailPrint 'QueryServiceStatus: Type=$3, CurrentState=$4 ControlsAccepted=$5'
        ${EndIf}
        ${If} $4 = ${SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING}
        ${OrIf} $4 = ${SERVICE_PAUSED}
            System::Call 'ADVAPI32::ControlService(ir1, i${SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE}, ir2)i.r3 ?e'
            Pop $9
            ${If} $3 = 0
                DetailPrint 'ControlService(SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE) failed with error $9'
            ${Else}
                DetailPrint 'Resuming "${MyServiceName}"...'
                !insertmacro WaitForServiceRunningStatus $1 5000
            ${EndIf}
        ${ElseIf} $4 = ${SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING}
            !insertmacro WaitForServiceRunningStatus $1 5000
        ${ElseIf} $4 >= ${SERVICE_STOPPED}
            ${If} $4 = ${SERVICE_RUNNING}
                DetailPrint "Service already running"
            ${Else}
                System::Call 'ADVAPI32::StartService(ir1, i0, i0)i.r3 ?e'
                Pop $9
                ${If} $3 = 0
                    DetailPrint 'StartService failed with error $9'
                ${Else}
                    DetailPrint 'Starting "${MyServiceName}"...'
                    !insertmacro WaitForServiceRunningStatus $1 9000
                ${EndIf}
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
        System::Free $2
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::CloseServiceHandle(i.r1)'
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::CloseServiceHandle(i.r0)'
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```